# Дистрибутив unix. Какой выбрать?

Tags: unix, javafx

Какой unix-дистрибутив лучше выбрать для live-системы с одним javafx приложением с максимальной производительностью и легкой настройкой?

Буду очень благодарен за линки на описания того, как это воплотить в жизнь.

Comment: Но соль вопроса не в дистрибутиве, а в совместимости и производительности с программным комплексом с ява-машиной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рейтинг дистрибутивов можно посмотреть на этом [сайте](http://distrowatch.com/). Выгодно ставить то же, что и стоит у большинства. Это позволяет в случае возникновения проблем увеличить шансы на нахождение их решения.

Answer (score 0):

[Список](http://www.livebsd.com/) популярных Live-CD дистрибутивов, основанных на BSD

Answer (score 0):

PC-BSD лучше!

Answer (score 0):

Debian есно, что же еще??? Сам собираешь, можно ручками, можно конструктором. Можно на флешку сразу залить можно на болванку... Можно и менюшку с допами.. В общем, имхо, аналогов Debian нет - просто, быстро, надежно и, в отличии от RH подобных - всё лежит там, где и должно лежать.